# Bignumber.js shiftedBy() is not a function

Tags: javascript, function

So I'm currently working on a project where I have very large numbers and I need to shift the comma so it outputs only the first few decimals before and the rest after the comma. I tried:

```
import BigNumber from bignumber.js

var x = new BigNumber(12345678);
var y = x.shiftedBy(-7);
```

So it should be: 1.2345678
However it tells me that "shiftedBy is not a function".

Of course I could do something like:

```
import BigNumber from bignumber.js

var x = new BigNumber(12345678);
var y = x/10000000;
```

But that looks awful and even worse when the numbers get larger.
So why is "shiftedBy" not working?
Sorry if that's a stupid question. I'm still learning Javascript :D

Comment: Something else must be going on since the [same code works in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qtp083ve/).

Comment: Thanks for the help. I wrote the B as a lower case letter in my project... Problem solved

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out:
In my code I wrote `shiftedby()` insead of `shiftedBy()`.
So after copy-pasting my code from here to my project, it worked fine. :D